# IntelliJ - Keyboard shortcut to open the file under the cursor

Tags: javascript, macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Sometimes I have a reference to another file in my source and I want to view the content of the file.

If for example I have an html file that refers to javascript files:

```
...
<script src="../js/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="./actions.js"></script>
...
```

I would like to put the cursor on `actions.js` and "zoom" into the file to open it in IntelliJ.

On a Mac I can press <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>up</kbd> twice to select the file name, then <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>, then <kbd>enter</kbd>.  But it is a bit complicated.

Is there a more direct keyboard shortcut to open the file?

I know about <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> that jumps to a declaration, for instance of a java class, but I cannot make it work on a file name.

Comment: Just double checked a JSP and an HTML page in the project I'm working on and both ⌘ Click and ⌘ B work for file imports.  One was a .jpg and one was require.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Click</kbd>, but without the mouse correct?
Then the shortcut is <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.  I always use this for [reference](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

Comment: Thanks.  I tried ⌘B already, but it says "Cannot find declaration to go to". I think it works for example to find the declaration of a java class, but not for an include or a link in html.

Comment: No it works for links to JS files in HTML/JSPs also.  I use it all the time (And I just double checked to make sure it works).  It must not be a proper link.  I've also had, where the path is correct, but intellij cant seem to find it, but more often than not it finds it.

Comment: OK, frankly, I cannot make it work.  I will accept your answer because you give the shortcut that _should_ work.  Why it doesn't work for me is another question.  Possibly the configuration of my project.

Comment: I'm using DataGrip which is based on the same JetBrains platform and this works in Oracle SQL Plus/SQLcl scripts that include other files using `@included_file.sql` syntax. The cursor must be positioned right to `@` and `.sql` extension, which is optional in SQL Plus, must be included.

Comment: goto definition is not the same as goto file. especially if the file is not a source file (like xml/html/yaml).

Comment: Please update your reference. Otherwise... thanks :)